# deploy java EE application on jboss 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, jboss

i have a java EE application ,which contains web module and entity module.i have created the application using netbeans, glassfish and javadb. i want to deploy this application to jboss 7. how do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Paste your deployment artifact in:

```
JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments
```

I would suggest using Eclipse Indigo with the JBoss Tools plugins installed for development on JBoss AS. You can easily find them through the Eclipse Marketplace.

Here is a [nice video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuFaYYQVJP0) describing how to deploy your application on JBoss AS 7.x. It describes 5 ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to add the following in your WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml file;

```
    <jboss-web>
      <context-root>/mywebapp</context-root>
      <virtual-host>example.com</virtual-host>
    </jboss-web>
```

And you are logged in to the Administration Console, go to Deployments > Manage Deployments.In the Deployments screen, click on Add Content and upload your war file. So see this [article](https://support.eapps.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/420#deployment_examples_using_jboss_7_in_standalone_mode) to get more details information.

Comment: You don't need a `jboss-web.xml` for JBoss AS 7.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with u brother